# SQLAlchemy IntegrityError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt, pyside, python-elixir

I'm having a problem using SQLAlchemy with PySide(PyQt).  I'm trying to pop-up a `QtGui.QDialog`, but when I do this SQLAlchemy throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\preo\preodb\dbviewandmodel.py", line 32, in rowCount
    return len(self.rows())    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\preo\preodb\dbviewandmodel.py", line 30, in rows
    return self.tableobj.query.all()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 1579, in all
return list(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 1688, in __iter__
    self.session._autoflush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 862, in _autoflush
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1388, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1469, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 302, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 446, in execute
    uow
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1878, in _save_obj
    execute(statement, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1191, in execute
    params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1271, in _execute_clauseelement
    return self.__execute_context(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1302, in __execute_context
    context.parameters[0], context=context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1401, in _cursor_execute
    context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1394, in _cursor_execute
    context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 299, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC
SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of UNIQUE KEY
constraint 'UQ__users__F3DBC5720DAF0CB0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
object 'dbo.users'. (2627) (SQLExecDirectW); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)") u'INSERT INTO users
(username, fullname, email, passwordmd5) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
(None, None, None, None)
```

This is particularly troubling because I have no code, anywhere, that even attempts to insert records into SQL; I am only ever attempting to query data from the database.  In fact, my DB model is read-only with respect to what PySide/PyQt are doing (i.e., I'm using a `QtGui.QTableView` model/view and there is no `insertRows` function in that model).

I have no idea what's going on or how to solve it - again, I have no code to modify SQL records at all, but still SQLAlchemy attempts to be inserting blank records into one of my SQL tables.  All I can see, in the background, is the `QTableView` data model is querying the database A LOT.  It just seems that when I popup this `QDialog` (which does have some code in it to query some table column) this error is thrown.  Oddly, this isn't consistent, sometime the popup appears first before the exception, sometimes the popup appears after the exception.  Under normal circumstances, the `QTableView` data model works great, just not when I popup this dialog (and ironically, the popup isn't using any `QTableView` at all, just standard widgets like QLineEdit, QTextEdit, etc.)

If it helps, I'm using Python 2.7 with SQLAlchemy 0.6.6 (also with Elixir 0.7.1), and PySide 1.0.0 (and PyQt4 4.8.3).  I'm on Windows 7 using SQL 2008 R2 (Express).  And yes, I've tried rebooting the PC, but the problem still occurs after a reboot.  I'm reluctant to post more code because I have a lot of it in this particular project and I can't nail down the problem anything specific.

I'm hoping someone might know of oddities in SQLAlchemy and/or PyQt that might be related to this.  I'm also hoping I can continue using SQLAlchemy as I have a large data model built; I'm reluctant, at this point, to abandon this and use PyQt's SQL features.

Comment: The select statement might not be doing anything, but something is probably happening to the session before the query. When the query runs, it flushes any changes still to be made (such as inserting a user). Can we see the rest of the "dbviewandmodel.py" file?

Comment: I still was not doing any database modifications of any kind when this is happening (no inserts, no edits on any data in that database), just querying data.  I think I've found a way of NOT making this crash happen (not really a fix, more like, I can get it to not happen by not doing something specific).  I'll add an answer as it's a bit long winded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make this problem go away, but it's still not really clear to me why SQLAlchemy was trying to insert rows in my database - that really bothers me, but it's not happening anymore.

At any rate, what was, I think, happening, was related to my SQLAlchemy data model and the way I was accessing it, here is a snippet of that model:

```
from elixir import *

metadata.bind = 'mssql+pyodbc://username:password/dbname'
metadata.bind.echo = False

class Users(Entity):
    using_options(tablename = 'users')
    username = Field(String(50), unique=True)
    fullname = Field(String(255))
    email = Field(String(255))
    passwordmd5 = Field(String(32))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Users ({})({})({})>".format(self.username, self.fullname, self.email)
    def prettyname(self):
        return {'username':'User Name', 'fullname':'Full Name', 'email':'Email Address', 'passwordmd5':'$hidden$'}
```

In my code I needed a way of getting 'pretty' label names for a GUI without having to hard code this in a GUI (I've been trying to create a dynamic way of building GUI forms).  So, I added the 'prettyname' method to my data model to give me some application specific metadata in that data model.  All I'm doing is returning a dictionary of items.

I had a secondary problem in that sometimes I needed to get this data from the class instance for Users and sometimes for a query result for Users (for example, Users.get_by(id=1)).  As it turned out, retrieving this data had to be done in two ways.  In the class instances I had to get the value this way:

```
prettyname = Users().prettyname()['username']
```

But when I was using query results it was:

```
prettyname = queryresult.prettyname()['username']
```

SQLAlchemy seems to have a real problem when I was using the former method (the class instance method) - as this was being used everytime I was seeing the crash.  When I was using the latter instance I was never seeing a crash.  Still, I needed access to that metadata in the class instance.

The fix, or should I say what turned out to fix this came from another Stackoverflow article (thank you everyone at Stackoverflow - I'd be nothing without you).  I changed the structure of the dbmodel:

```
class Users(Entity):
    using_options(tablename = 'users')
    username = Field(String(50), unique=True, info={'prettyname':'User Name'})
    fullname = Field(String(255), info={'prettyname':'Full Name'})
    email = Field(String(255), info={'prettyname':'Email Address'})
    passwordmd5 = Field(String(32), info={'hidden':True})
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Users ({})({})({})>".format(self.username, self.fullname, self.email)
```

This allows me to use a common method of introspection to get the dictionary data in the info argument, regardless if I'm looking at a class instance, or a query result.  In this case I use the '.table' method of either the class or query result, then get the column that I need (.c), then use the .info method of that column to return the dictionary.

Whatever the case, now SQLAlchemy no longer tries to arbitrarily insert rows in the database anymore.

Comment: As you never posted the exact code causing the problem, I can't be sure on this. However, you have a snippet above that reads `prettyname = Users().prettyname()['username']`. Because you use Elixer, this line could cause a write to the users table. `Users()` will create a new Users instance. Elixer will add this to the session. A query that is done after this call will try to commit the new Users instance. Therefore, if this snippet was in your code, the insert into the users table would have been the correct behavior.

Comment: That makes sense, especially given I couldn't say for sure where in code the problem was occurring.  That line of code was as close as I could get to where the problem could have been.  I'll try and avoid using the Users() construct in this way going forward.  Thanks!